Add missing includes without path
I am using clangd with VSCode. Clangd offers the possibility to add missing includes. When doing so, it (sometimes? couldn´t figure out when) automatically adds the relative or absolute path to the include directive.
The latter causes problems when compiling on different OS's (in my case Linux and Termux (on my mobile)) as the absolute (system) paths are obviously different.
For example, instead of
#include "Header.h"
it will add
#include "/home/user/path/to/the/Header.h"
Of course I can manually delete the path, but I wonder:
Does someone know if there is a possibility to disable this behavior and make it omit the path?
I tried to google it, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything...
Thanks in advance
Edit: Minimal example
Structure:
./
- .clangd
- compile_commands.json
- bin/
- build/
- include/
--- Header.h
--- Subheader.h
- src/
--- main.cpp`

Contents:
// .clangd
Diagnostics:
  UnusedIncludes: Strict
  MissingIncludes: Strict

// Subheader.h
#ifndef IG20240815185417
#define IG20240815185417

struct Subheader {
    int i{2};
};

#endif

// Header.h
#ifndef IG20240520170135
#define IG20240520170135
    
#include "Subheader.h"
    
struct Header {
  Subheader sh{};
};

#endif

// main.cpp
#include "Header.h"

int main() {
  Header h{};
  Subheader sh{};
  return 0;
}

Compile command (with compile_commands.json creation):
clang++ -o build/main.o -c src/main.cpp -MJ build/main.o.json -I./include && clang++ -o bin/main.exe build/main.o && sed -e '1s/^/[\n/' -e '$s/,$/\n]/' build/*.o.json > compile_commands.json

Note that compile_commands.json will be created via the compile command. If it does not work on your machine, here is the basic compile command and the final content of the .json file. You will have to adjust the directory to match your system!
Compile command (without compile_commands.json creation):
clang++ -o build/main.o -c src/main.cpp -I./include && clang++ -o bin/main.exe build/main.o

// compile_commands.json
[
{ "directory": "/ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/WORKING/DIRECTORY", "file": "src/main.cpp", "output": "build/main.o", "arguments": ["/usr/bin/clang++", "-xc++", "src/main.cpp", "-o", "build/main.o", "--driver-mode=g++", "-c", "-I", "./include", "--target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"]}
]

Observation:
When viewing main.cpp (in VSCode) it shows a blue squiggle line below Subheader, hinting that the respective header is missing / not directly included (but known via Header.h).
When choosing the QuickFix option, it adds the include-directive like this:
#include "/path/to/working/directory/include/Subheader.h"

Never happened to me. We're going to need a [mcve] (your directory structure, compile_commands.json and/or Clangd config, etc).

Added the requested minimal reproducible example.

Sorry for the delay. Try specifying an absolute path instead of src/main.cpp in compile_commands.json.

Adding it to both/either the "file": and/or the "arguments": part didn't change the situation (I did clean clangd index in between).
I am pretty sure that the "directory": in compile_commands.json is considered anyway, so I am not surprised.
As an aside: As the compile_command.json is created via clang++, changes to it are not persistent anyway.
I am in fact fine, if there is no clear/obvious solution. Just thought, someone might have a known solution already. Thanks for your support thou. (Not sure if I should mark a question solved if no solution was found...)

Okay, I reproduced it. It seems to be a bug in MissingIncludes: Strict (if you remove this setting and remove the include, it will suggest to add the missing include correctly, without the full path). I suggest reporting it. You can then post an answer below (with a link to the bug), and press the checkmark next to it to mark the question as solved.

Thank you for your support / efforts. I followed your suggestion and reported a bug as well as putting it an answer.

As there seems to be no solution so far, I reported a bug here.
I followed HolyBlackCats suggestion:
I removed UnusedIncludes: Strict from .clangd, after which it won't show any hint or quickfix option at all. Therefore unfortunately this does note solve the issue.
Note: When hovering the Subheader type keyword, the hover info panel states: provided by: "/path/to/working/directory/include/Subheader.h". Hovering over Header instead states: provided by: "Header.h".
Edit: I just found out that removing the MissingIncludes: Strict line, but keeping the UnusedIncludes: Strict produces the expected results

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
